# Timeout does not work if server does not respond

Tags: java, http, timeout, connection

I have the problem that I never get a SocketTimeOutException when server not responding. After 30 seconds I get an IOException instead.

What do I need to do to get a timeout when server is not responding?

This is my code where the first URL works and the second results in an IOException instead of SocketTimeOutException.

public class TestConnection {

```
public static final int TIMEOUT_VALUE = 5000;

public static void main(String[] arg){

    try {
        URL testUrl = new URL("http://www.doublegames.com/images/games140/scrabble-cubes-online_140x140.jpg");
        testTimeOut(testUrl);
        testUrl = new URL("http://tamblang.co.cc/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/cd7ce2_command-038-conquer-4-tiberian-twilight-140x140.jpg");
        testTimeOut(testUrl);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }
}
private static void testTimeOut(URL testUrl) {
    try {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        HttpURLConnection testConnection = (HttpURLConnection) testUrl.openConnection();
        testConnection.setConnectTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);
        testConnection.setReadTimeout(TIMEOUT_VALUE);


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(testConnection.getInputStream()));
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Elapsed (ms): " + elapsed / 1000000);
        System.out.println("Connection worked for " + testUrl);
    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("More than " + TIMEOUT_VALUE + " elapsed." + testUrl);
    } catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("No timeout for " + testUrl);
    }
}
```

}

I have also tried with apaches HttpClient but same thing there.

```
private static void testTimeOut(URL testUrl) {
    long start = 0;
    try {
        start = System.nanoTime();

        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_VALUE);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_VALUE);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(testUrl.toString());
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget);


        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to bother about connection release
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                // do something useful with the response
                 long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
                System.out.println("Elapsed (ms): " + elapsed / 1000000);
                System.out.println("Connection worked for " + testUrl);

            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - start;
        System.out.println("Elapsed (ms): " + elapsed / 1000000);
        System.out.println("No timeout for " + testUrl + " after " + elapsed / 100000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the following to the IOException catch: `System.err.println(e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: "second results in an IOException". *What* IOException? Never fail to log or print an exception.

Comment: java.net.UnknownHostException: tamblang.co.cc
 at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
 at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
 at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
 at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:158)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to open a connection via `testUrl.openConnection()` where `testUrl` is of type `URL`. Well, if you have a look at the specific [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection%28%29), you'll notice that `URL.openConnection()` will never throw a `SocketTimeoutException`. It can only throw an `IOException`.

Comment: FYI `SocketTimeoutException` extends from `IOException`. Most Java code that throws the `SocketTimeoutException` is documented only as `IOException`.

Comment: It does not matter what exception I get, what I am trying to achieve is to have the timeout kick in after 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the IOException and throw a new SocketTimeOutException in the catch block

Comment: Yes but I want the timeout to result in a SocketTimeOutException after 5 seconds, now I get an IOException after 30 seconds.

Comment: You can start a Thread/Timer and add a listener to it.
When it expires after 5 seconds you can throw the SocketTimeOutException

Comment: I think that sounds like the best solution, can't solve it in any other way. Do you have any code example? I was thinking of an Executor/Future solution.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. The connection object is created by invoking the openConnection method on a URL.
> 2. The setup parameters and general request properties are manipulated.
> 3. The actual connection to the remote object is made, using the connect method.
> 4. The remote object becomes available. The header fields and the contents of the remote object can be accessed.